# Samba 4 шара не появляется при обзоре сети

Tags: linux, centos, samba

Обновил сервер до CentOs 7, обновилась и самба с 3 до 4. Применил старые конфиги с самбы 3. Сервер работает напрямую по ip, но, при обзоре сети его не видно. КОнфиг настраивался при помощи webmin.

```
[global]
guest account = nobody
idmap gid = 1001-3000
hostname lookups = Yes
create mask = 0666
interfaces = lo enp3s6
map to guest = Bad User 
null passwords = yes
hide dot files = yes
hosts allow = 127. 192.168.1.
netbios name = MEDIA
idmap uid = 1001-3000  
dos charset = CP1251  
local master = Yes 
workgroup = WORKGROUP
os level = 255
debug level = 2  
directory mask = 0777
security = share
bind interfaces only = Yes
winbind separator = +
max log size = 50
wins support = no

[disk1]
path = /mnt/disk1
    comment = snark share
    force user = nobody
    read only = No
    browseable = Yes
    public = yes  
    writeable = yes
    hosts allow = 192.168.1.
    create mask = 0666

[disk2]
path = /mnt/disk2
    comment = snark share
    force user = nobody
    force group = nobody
    read only = No
    browseable = Yes
    public = yes  
    writeable = yes
    hosts allow = 192.168.1.
    force create mode = 0664
    force directory mode = 0775

[disk3]
path = /mnt/disk3
    comment = snark share
    force user = nobody
    force group = nobody
    read only = No
    browseable = Yes
    public = yes  
    writeable = yes
    hosts allow = 192.168.1.
    force create mode = 0664
    force directory mode = 0775
```

Это файлопомойка в закрытой домашней сети. Все должно быть максимально открыто.

Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1):

У samba в Linux две службы, `smb` и `nmb`, вторая и отвечает за "видимость в сети" по имени, убедитесь что `nmb` выполняется.